# Is there no limit to power levels?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

Since Jiren and Frieza don't have godly ki, we are able to understand that you *can* attain the power of a god through regular training; that regular ki can go as high as divine ki.

Based on existing knowledge, how much roughly is Jiren's full power level? (the power he plans to use on Beyond Super Saiyan Blue Vegeta and 20+ Kaio-Ken Super Saiyan Blue Goku).

My guess is based on Super Gogeta's power level of 2,500,000,000 that Jiren's full power level is 189,000,000,000,000,000.

Comment: I don't think this question is opinion based. Using comparison of existing power levels, an answer could be concluded. Note, the OP isn't asking for an exact number.

Comment: There are 2 questions here: 1) How much roughly is Jiren's full power level?, and 2) is power level limitless? Please focus on a specific question.

Comment: There are no power levels in Dragon Ball super. Most of the answers here are based on opinion. Also, Super Gogeta is not canon. Comparing a canon character with someone who doesn't make any sense. A better question would be how strong is Jiren compared to Goku and Vegeta or other acharacters in the T.O.P.

Comment: What is this question asking? The question in the body is different from the one in the heading ("What is the limit to power levels" vs "What is Jiren's power level". And all the answers are talking about multipliers instead of either of these.

Comment: @ShayminGratitude Just the usual fan obsession about power numbers even though the series recognized it as awful and limiting and so abandoned it entirely ages ago.

Comment: This question was closed as "unfocused" because, after a long time, the issue hasn't been fixed: the title and the question body asked 2 different questions, and some of the existing answers were interpreting the question differently due to that.

Answer (score 0):

We have no idea which are the multipliers for super saiyan god and super saiyan blue, and we have no idea which is the current base power level of Goku and Vegeta, so it's impossible to give power levels with figures (numbers).

If we try to determine with a number the base power level of Goku and Vegeta (which seems to be about the same for both of them for the fights and sparrings they had in Dragon Ball Super) we find a lot of incongruences or very hard to fit situations. Also with the other transformations

- Fake Vegeta in base form (which is as strong as Vegeta) was able to defeat SSJ3 Gotenks.
- Goku in base form was able to overpower Freezer 4th form, Freezer 3rd form was able to almost kill super saiyajin Gohan.
- In one movie Beerus says Goku in base form isnt as strong as Freezer (4th form)

So according to some data, Goku or Vegeta base form could be weaker than a super saiyajin, and according to other data it could be stronger than a SSJ3. Situations like those can only be fixed with speculation, no with the dialogue or things said by the authors because they just didnt try to fix those inconsistencies. So, being us unable to give number estimations since they could vary very widely, I believe this is the only thing we can say.

Super Saiyan Blue Kaiokenx20 of Goku, plus Ultra Super Saiyan Blue Vegita which seems to be in a similar level than Goku Super Saiyan Blue Kaiokenx20 , gave some fight but no damage to Jiren. This tells us that Goku (who is using the power of 20 super saiyan blue) plus Vegeta who is using a similar power (who together has a power around x40 super saiyan blue) are weaker than Jiren. Then Jiren power level has to be somewhere between x50 to x100 super saiyan blue.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, no.
The multipliers were devised to keep in account how power scaling would work, in case the character undergoes any power up or transformation.

The multipliers assumed are:

- Kaioken = x1.5
- Kaioken x10 = x10
- Kaioken x20 = x20
- Super Saiyan = x50
- Super Saiyan 2 = x100
- Super Saiyan 3 = x400
- Super Saiyan God = x15,000
- Super Saiyan Blue = x25,000
- Ultra Instinct "Omen" = x150 Super Saiyan Blue

The numbers calculated can be assumed to be partially correct because no track of power level was kept after Dragon Ball Z.

- Goku (Suppressed) = 50,000,000,000
- Jiren (Extremely Suppressed++) = 1,000,000,000,000,000,000
- Goku (Super Saiyan) = 2,500,000,000,000
- Goku (Super Saiyan 2) = 5,000,000,000,000
- Goku (Super Saiyan God) = 750,000,000,000,000,000
- Goku (Super Saiyan Blue) = 37,500,000,000,000,000,000 (Qaudrillion)
- Goku (Super Saiyan Blue Kaioken x10) = 375,000,000,000,000,000,000
- Jiren (Less Suppressed+) = 400,000,000,000,000,000,000
- Goku (Super Saiyan Blue Kaioken x20) = 750,000,000,000,000,000,000
- Jiren (Less Suppressed+)=1,000,000,000,000,000,000,000
- Piccolo = 32,000,000,000
- Gohan (Suppressed) = 5,500,000,000
- Vegeta (Suppressed) = 25,000,000,000
- True Form Frieza = 5,000,000,000,000
- Krillin = 740,000,000
- Goku (Genki Dama/Spirit Bomb) = 900,000,000,000,000,000,000
- Goku (Ultra Instinct) = 3,500,000,000,000,000,000,000
- Jiren (Less Than 30%)=12,000,000,000,000,000,000,000

Source: [Dragon Ball Wikia](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page)

Comment: i assume by Wikia you're talking about the Dragon Ball Wikia. if not please update the link as to which wikia you are referring to

Comment: yeah, will do the same. Should I post other reference links as well?

Comment: if you use other sources to reference your answer then yeh it's a good idea

Comment: Could you please point to the specific Wikia articles mentioning this number? I failed to find the multipliers and exact power levels mentioned on this answer.

Answer (score -1):

Goku has broken every ceiling of power he's reached, and we know he's sure to reach another level of power. Just look at mastered Ultra instinct. If he learns how to control that power and use it at will, then that'll be yet another ceiling he's broken. (Side note) Gohan needs to step his game up to 100.